# How can i return a JSON object property

Tags: javascript, json

I want to do something like this:

```
function createParam(value, key = 'params') {
    return [key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}
}
```

So that i can do something like this:

```
const param1 = createParam(someVaue);
const param2 = createParam(someOtherValue, someKey);
const parameter = {param1, param2}
```

How can i do something like this?, currently i have problem with the `function createParam` because a syntax like the one above doesn't seem to exists.
**Update 01:**
Some of the answers suggested good solutions that works but just to clarify for anyone else who reads the question, the expected output for parameter is:

```
{key1: {value:'xx', name: ''},key2: {value:'xx', name: ''},key3: {value:'xx', name: ''},...}
```

Comment: What will you then do with `parameter`? Because I can think of at least a couple of ways.

Comment: you need to return `{[key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}}`

Comment: @I send the parameter to server in a specific format

Comment: @CodeManiac that doesn't work because the server side requires {key1: ..., key2:...}

Comment: @AliAhmadi you'll need to provide a more comprehensive example.

Comment: I'd say you can't do that. Why not calling createParam on an object and setting the property on `this` for example? It looks like you try to create a strange pattern.

Comment: @AliAhmadi you can merged the two object before assigning to parameter,  {...obj1, ...obj2} or `object.assign({},obj1,obj2)`, or pass the key/value pair as array and loop through them and build the desired object

Comment: return `{[key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}}` like @CodeManiac said, and then `const parameter = {...param1, ...param2}`

Comment: What does the backend expect? Where will this be used on the client? Since if this is for a form, the FormData API has builtin functions to append new key/value combinations.

Comment: Why not change the server code to receive a `param` array rather than sending an object with consecutive numeric keys?

Comment: why is ` name: ''` always empty? can that be hard coded? Did you actually mean an array like `[key1: {value:'xx', name: ''},key2: {value:'xx', name: ''},key3: {value:'xx', name: ''},...]`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the whole reason i am creating a param is because its going to do a lot more!! this is just a sudo code which all the unnecessary codes were deleted, and no i did not mean `[]` i meant `{}`

Comment: Is it an option to pass the `parameters` to the `createParam` function? Or call the function from the object, like `parameters.createParam(value, key)`?

Comment: @Rodris I hadn't consider giving `createParam` to parameter, that also can be an valid option, currently createParam is under a `serviceUtility` something like `staticServices.createParam()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intended behavior is not possible. But you can try the following

```
function createParam(value, key = 'params') {
    return {[key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}}
}
```

and you can do the below using ES6 syntax

```
const param1 = createParam(someVaue);
const param2 = createParam(someOtherValue, someKey);
const parameter = {...param1, ...param2}
```

or

```
const param1 = createParam(someVaue);
const param2 = createParam(someOtherValue, someKey);
const parameter = Object.assign({}, param1, param2);
```

```js
function createParam(value, key = 'params') {
    return {[key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}}
}
let someValue = "someValue";
let someOtherValue = "someOtherValue";
let someKey = "key1";

const param1 = createParam(someValue);
const param2 = createParam(someOtherValue, someKey);
const parameter = {...param1, ...param2}
console.log(parameter);

const param3 = createParam(someValue);
const param4 = createParam(someOtherValue, someKey);
const parameter2 = Object.assign({}, param3, param4);
console.log(parameter2);
```

Comment: key should be in square brackets

Comment: You could then do `const pArr = [];
pArr.push(param3);
pArr.push(param4);
pArr.push(createParam("manualValue", "key4"));
let paramter3 = {};
pArr.forEach(function(element) {
  Object.assign(paramter3, element);
});` with this

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler for each param to be a proper object, then spread them all in a new object.

```
const param1 = { params: 'someValue' };
const param2 = { [key]: 'someOtherValue' };
const parameter = {...param1, ...param2 }

// paramter = { params: 'someValue', [key]: 'someOtherValue' }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create temporaries object with only your param, 1 per param and then merge all those objects together. One way of doing it is using the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function createParam(value, key = 'params') {
    // added {} around the returns to return an object
    return {[key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}}
}

// create the params
const param1 = createParam(42);
console.log(param1)
const param2 = createParam(123, "key");
console.log(param2)

// merge the resultings objects using spread operator
const parameter = {...param1, ...param2}
console.log(parameter)
```

in case you have more params adding them to parameter at the time you create them can prevent you from having one big merge line at the end

```js
function createParam(value, key = 'params') {
    // added {} around the returns to return an object
    return {[key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}}
}

// create the parameter object
let parameter = {}

// merge each time you create a new param
parameter = {...parameter, ...createParam(42)}
parameter = {...parameter, ...createParam(123, "key")}
console.log(parameter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your base object to function to map custom property.
like this:

```
function mapProp( baseObject, customPropKey, value){
    return (baseObject[customPropKey] = value)
}
```

and call:

```
var myObject = {a1:'a1value'};
console.log(myObject); //{a1:'a1value'}
var newObject = mapProp(myObject, 'a2', 'a2value');
console.log(newObject); //{a1:'a1value', a2:'a2Value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best option is to set the attribute directly into the object. You could:

Pass the object as a parameter.

```
function createParam(obj, value, key = 'params') {
    obj[key] = {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''};
    return obj;
}
const parameter = {};
createParam(parameter, someValue);
createParam(parameter, someOtherValue, someKey);
```

Call the function from your object.

```
const parameter = {};
parameter.createParam = function(value, key = 'params') {
    this[key] = {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''};
    return this;
}
parameter.createParam(someValue);
parameter.createParam(someOtherValue, someKey);
```

Create a class.

```
function Parameters() {
    this.createParam = function(value, key = 'params') {
        this[key] = {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''};
        return this;
    }
}
parameter = new Parameters();
parameter.createParam(someValue);
parameter.createParam(someOtherValue, someKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the **createParam** like this:

```
function createParam(value, key = 'params') {
    return {[key]: {value: JSON.stringify(value) ,name: ''}}
}
```

now, whenever you call the createParam function. It will return an object like:

```
const param1 = createParam(someVaue); //{ someVaue: { value: someVaue, name: '' } }
```

Comment: what's this syntax with `:` you use in your 2nd code block ? doesn't seems to work in firefox